# EGit in eclipse not detecting changes in a JAR file

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I am using git to check in codes from eclipse and my project uses "SparkChat.jar" for it's chat feature. I modified the code for sparkchat a little and generated an updated SparkChat.jar, but when i tried checking in, git doesn't recognize that SparkChat.jar has been modified.

Is there anyway i can 'tell' git that SparkChat.jar is dirty and needs to be checked in?

Edit: To clarify, i am using EGit implementation in Java Eclipse, not command line.

Comment: try running git update-index --no-assume-unchanged path/to/file

Comment: also storing binary files are not of a problem but versioning is. use git-lfs to do that instead

Comment: @ankidaemon The question is not about the command line Git, but about EGit which uses JGit, a Git implementation in Java.

Comment: Yes, sorry i wasn't clear enough. It's as @howlger mentioned. I am not using command lines.

Answer (score 0):

Hit the ***Refresh*** button in the toolbar of the ***Git Staging*** or ***Git Repositories*** view to synchronize Eclipse with the changed files of the file system:

[image]

If it is a file in a project, a *Refresh* (<kbd>F5</kbd>) in the *Project Explorer* or **Package Explorer** should also work.

Comment: Hi i did that but it didn't appear. Frankly all i modified was just one line of code so it didn't change the size of the jar file. Not sure if that affects.

Comment: Where exactly did you hit Refresh? Is the JAR file contained in an Eclipse project or only in a Git repository? A JAR file is a ZIP file which stores files with time stamps. From Git's point of view, if a byte is different, the binary file has changed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, there is a bug (or intended "feature"?!?). You have to close and reopen Eclipse! :-( That's the only way with my Eclipse to see file system changes in the 'Git Repositories' Windows! :-((